# Odd TABLE sizing behaviour

Tags: html, css, html-table

I can't understand why the `table` sizing is working the way it is.  Here is my example HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Table sizing test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <style>
        .tab-strip {
            overflow: hidden;
            white-space: nowrap;
        }
        .tab-strip .tab-button {
            display: inline-block;
        }
        .tab-strip .tab-button td {
            background-color: yellow;
        }
        .tab-strip .tab-button td:first-child {
            background-color: green !important;
            width: 100px;
        }
    </style>
        <div>
            <table align="center" border="1">
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top">
                        <div class="tab-strip">
                            <table class="tab-button">
                                <tr>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td>TEST1</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <table class="tab-button">
                                <tr>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td>TEST2</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <table class="tab-button">
                                <tr>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td>TEST3</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <table class="tab-button">
                                <tr>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td>TEST4</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <table class="tab-button">
                                <tr>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td>TEST5</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <table class="tab-button">
                                <tr>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td>TEST6</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've put it in a jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/90674xsg/

When the window is made narrower, the `table` keeps shrinking (smaller than its content) until a certain point, and then stops (causing a horizontal scrollbar to appear in the result window).  What determines this minimum width, though?

UPDATE:
It's been pointed out to me that the table width is determined by adding up the content-derived width of cells that actually contain content.  So the "TESTx" cells' widths are counted, but the empty cell widths are ignored even though they have a fixed width of 100px.  How can i make the minimum `table` width include their widths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tables are kind of weird, there's good reason that modern web development has steered away from them.

Adding the css [min-width](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-width.asp) property seems to do the trick for me, but I only tested in chrome.

```
.tab-strip .tab-button td:first-child {
    background-color: green !important;
    width: 100px;
    min-width: 100px;
}
```

[See updated fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/90674xsg/12/). If that doesn't work, you can try forcing it to stay open with padding instead of width - or add an empty div to the td that has a width of 100px.

Comment: The disadvantage to forcing the width with padding, though, is you won't be able to place any content inside it.